# How to use if-else block in Python

Tags: python

I got a question about if-else block in Python, here is an example:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = [i if i%2 else i+1 for i in a]
# following sentence is wrong
c = [i if i%2 for i in a else i+1]
```

But in some cases, `if` can be wrriten after `for`, just like this:

```py
d = [i for i in a if a%2]
```

I wonder the reason about this, Thank you all!

**This question has already been solved, Thank you again!!!**

Comment: Your last example doesn't have `for` anywhere.

Comment: There's no `for` statement in the second part of the example. The syntax is pretty consistent to your `b = ` statement

Comment: this is a list comprehension, search on the internet you easily found it.

Comment: You can use single expression in List comprehension and `i if i%2 else i+1` work as ternary operator in python

Comment: There's literally thousands of tutorials in dozens of languages on that, why you did not do any research on your own?

Comment: there is no relation between 'for' and 'if', in the second part you have used ternary operator.

Comment: @KlasŠ. Python syntax is so different from any other language that even experienced developers (in other languages) would be confused by the inversion of the condition and result. It's a bit similar to how some Python developers confuse UTF8 for escape sequences. To developers working on other languages the answer is obvious because their languages always supported Unicode. To someone coming from Python 2, not really

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the last example. Actually, I just want to show this just like the kind person @ThePyGuy mentioned below:   `x = [i for i in <iterable> if <condition>]`. I used to be confused about ternary operator, and thanks a lot for all the comments!

Comment: make it as solved! if u done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways when you can actually use `if else` in Python. The very basic usage is of course the execution of block of code conditionally:

```py
if <condition>:
    <body>
else:
    <body>
```

The if block will be executed when the condition is true, otherwise else block comes into execution.

Another use case is when you want to assign values conditionally:

```py
x = y if <condition> else z
```

In above conditional assignment, the variable x is assigned value of y if the condition is true, other wise it is assigned the value of z. It is widely used in comprehension and return statements as well: `[i if i%2==0 else i+1 for i in <iterable>]`

Another use case is using `if` only, this is used in comprehension to filter out some values:

```py
x = [i for i in <iterable> if <condition>]
```

The above expression will include only the items from iterable for which condition holds true.

Another use case is for `else`, it is quite unique to Python which allows using of `else` block after a loop:

```py
for i in <iterable>:
   <loop body>
else:
    <else body>
```

The `else` part will be executed if loop exits normally without a break statement that means the else part is executed even if the code doesn't enter the loop body.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description, I've learnt a lot in your answer!

Answer (score 1):

This type of if-else expression is officially (in the Python docs) called a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary#conditional-expressions), also known as a [ternary conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

In your second and third examples, you combine this with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) - a for loop in list-brackets.

In your second example, you place the conditional expression (correctly) before the for loop of the list comprehension. This is a valid syntax. For each item that is looped over, the if-else expression is evaluated.

In your thrid example, you place the for loop between the if and the else. This is invalid syntax and to be honest, I don't know what you expect of the output.

In end of your question you state that in some cases the `for` can be put before the `else` (and after the `if`). In the example you give, there is no `for`.

Comment: Thank you! I used to be confused about ternary operator, and your answer is very beneficial to me

Comment: @wgt good to hear. If this is the “best” answer for you, please accept it by clicking the check-mark at the left of my answer.